# How to construct graph based on triple list in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, nlp, azure-cosmosdb, triplestore

I have extracted information from a given text, the result is a triple list in the `RDF` format(`entity1, entity2, releation`). I'd like to construct a knowledge graph using the triple list, however, cosmos db graph API does not provide such APIs. So basically I have two questions

1. How to import a triple list to construct a graph in Azure Cosmos db? Specifically, it would be better if there is a C# solution;
2. Is there such API that allows me to query the knowledge graph using SPARQL?

I'm a newbie at NLP field, please correct me if you find any mistake in my description.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/d5734c02-555b-ed11-a81b-000d3ae49307

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to write an application using one of the Cosmos DB SDKs and convert your triple list into Gremlin statements that can be executed by Cosmos to seed the database.

SPARQL is not natively supported, Gremlin is the only graph query language available at this time. However, Cosmos data can be exported into HDInsight for analysis so you could install SPARQL on your HDInsight cluster and then execute whatever SPARQL you wanted using Spark.